# Use of "concretely" for "specifically"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have sometimes seen people using *concretely* in places where I would normally use *specifically*. I am not sure if both words correctly apply or if *concretely* is just a mistranslation from another language. For example:

> We do have contacts with people abroad, **concretely** with various trade
>   unions...
>
> We will only deal with mathematical problems, or, more **concretely**,
>   with a certain subset of such problems.
>
> We detected certain problems with some measures, **concretely** with the
>   extreme values obtained from some indicators.

Is this correct?

Comment: For what it's worth, to my ear, the middle one is fine and the other two are horrible. A comma after *concretely* helps a bit with the first.

Comment: I tried to tag the question for `correctness` but it turned into `grammaticality`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is not about grammaticality, since the adverb is used grammatically in all cases. Rather it is about meaning: *concretely* is normally not used when one really means *specifically*, even though dictionaries give as a synonym of *concrete* the words *specific* and *definite*.

If a thing is described as *concrete*, we understand it to be "existing in material or physical form; real or solid; not abstract" [NOAD]. This dictionary goes on to list "specific; definite" as an alternate meaning, but then illustrates the use with this example:

> I haven't got any concrete proof.

That still means "real" or "substantial" proof more than it does "specific" or "definite" proof. It means proof that you can physically observe.

Even when you use *concretely* as in your second example, its meaning shades toward the nuance of something that is not abstract. What if the "certain subset of such problems" is actually *more* abstract than the problems in general? Then you are simply making a poor word choice, one that militates against your meaning.

Once again, Mark Twain said it best:

> The difference between the right word and almost the right word is the difference between lightning and a lightning bug.