# "specifically" vs "particularly" vs "concretely"

Tags: meaning, readability

In my publication text I wrote

> The goal of this work is DAC, which can analyze data that could not be
> processed before, specifically incomplete data.

I had the paper corrected by a professional proofreader and was told to write

> The goal of this work is DAC, which can analyze data that could not be
> processed before, **particularly** incomplete data.

However, "incomplete data" is the only kind of "data that could not be processed before". And as far as I understand "particularly" is more like "I include all or at least a lot of types of data that could not be processed before, but I discuss *incomplete data* more than the other types".

So I wrote

> The goal of this work is DAC, which can analyze data that could not be
> processed before, **concretely** incomplete data.

Now, another professional proofreader told me I should replace **concretely** and write **specifically** instead.

Now I am confused. What are the different meanings of those three words and why were they corrected "back and forth"?

Comment: **Specifically** indicates that DAC perhaps cannot handle complete data. -- **Particularly** indicates that DAC deals with all data but specialises in incomplete data -- **Concretely** is plain wrong.

Comment: You were right in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> However, "incomplete data" is the only kind of "data that could not be processed before". And as far as I understand "particularly" is more like "I include all or at least a lot of types of data that could not be processed before, but I discuss incomplete data more than the other types".

If this is what you meant, then your original text was correct and the original proofreader either misunderstood your intent, or made a language error. If "incomplete data" is the only kind of data that could not be processed before, then I would state very concretely (  ) that "specifically" is the correct word, and "particularly" is wrong, and misleading.

"Concretely" is a bit trickier to use, but I think this post is quite useful, particularly the first comment to the original question, which refers to the specific examples given and states concretely which of them sounds acceptable.

[Use of "concretely" for "specifically"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63811/use-of-concretely-for-specifically?rq=1)